# In GeoServer 2.16 or 2.15 colours raster with 5 bands shown as black and white raster

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms, symbology, sld

I have problem with 5 bands colour raster. When I open the raster in ESRI ArcGIS or QGIS the raster is open with colours, but when I uploaded it to  GeoServer software the WMS shows it only with black and white colours. I guess I have to do some settings, but I don't know what and where.

Comment: You must select 3 bands out of the 5 that you have to stand for red, green, and blue. I guess that with GeoServer the selection is done with a SLD style file.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html#channelselection) you need to use the `<ChannelSelection>` element of the `RasterSymbolizer` to select which 3 of your 5 channel you wish to use for red, green and blue.

```
<ChannelSelection>
  <RedChannel>
    <SourceChannelName>1</SourceChannelName>
  </RedChannel>
  <GreenChannel>
    <SourceChannelName>2</SourceChannelName>
  </GreenChannel>
  <BlueChannel>
    <SourceChannelName>3</SourceChannelName>
  </BlueChannel>
</ChannelSelection>
```